# is it possible to solve this with just one regex?

Tags: regex

I would like to know if there is a regular expression that given for example this input:

> lkjs kjsfjk ijsfj á **13total** wer6klje additional lñk jshv kjsdfjk dj d **22total**  kejk jksfljkakvhjr j  **3total** fkljbher jr6 hrew7 hwr **41total** sfdkj additional iuwefjkwf7 7erfh sf **5total** klj kj kjsef87 jhwfe7 89 jhf

could output these 3 matches, which are numbers followed by `total`, that do not contain the word `additional` after (and before finding the next number):

```
22
3
5
```

So, for example I didn't match 13 because

> **13total** wer6klje additional lñk jshv kjsdfjk dj d **22total**

contains the word `additional`

And I didn't match `41` because

> **41total** sfdkj additional iuwefjkwf7 7erfh sf **5total**

contains the word additional

let me explain the input structure used in the example:

```
randomText 13total randomText aditional randomText
22total randomText
3total randomText
41total randomText aditional randomText
5total randomText
```

So basically the input is something like:

```
randomText X_total randomText_that_contains_or_not_'additional'
X_total randomText_that_contains_or_not_'additional'
....
X_total randomText_that_contains_or_not_'additional'
```

I know how to solve the problem using some additional code (using several patterns and matches, if-else structures...) but the system I'm working with, cannot make use of those. It just can be fed up with one regular expression (it's a complicated system, not easy to modify).

So, for example, with the regular expression `[0-9]+(?=total)` I would get this matches: `13`, `22`, `3`, `41`, `5`

but as I said I just need `22`, `3`, `5`

Can anybody build a more complex regular expression that matches those 3 numbers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is possible (given that your regex flavour supports [lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html))

```
\d+(?=total(?!\D*additional))
```

[See it here on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/uT4fT3#pcre)

`\d+` matches one ore more digits

`(?=total(?!\D*additional))` nested lookaround assertions. Digits has to be followed by "total" not followed by additional (with only non digits inbetween)

A more advanced example based on Bergis comment:

```
\d+(?=total(?!(?:.(?!\d+total))*additional))
```

[See it on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/tD7dL9#pcre)

Here I searching for additional as long as I not find `\d+total`

Comment: `\D` is a nice trick that works on the presented example input, but I'm not sure whether the actual text is guaranteed not to contain any digits. Can you make make it so that the text before `additional` is only not allowed to contain `\d+total`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use (the `total` will always be preceded by a digit, right?)

```
\d+(?=total(?!(?:\D|\d(?!total))*additional))
```

---

**Explanation**

The idea is to forbid any `additional` before the next `<digit>total`:

```
\d+                     # digits
(?=total                # followed by total
    (?!                 # not followed by...
        (?:             
            \D++        # not a digit (possessive quantifier)
        |               # OR
            \d(?!total) # a digit, but not followed by total
        )*+             # any number of times
     additional
    )
)
```

The negative look ahead will fail the regex if it finds one, and we're sure not to pass over a `<digit>total` thanks to `(?:\D|\d(?!total))`.

See [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/pO4zU4).